# How do I reference a child of an eq() jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table I'm trying to derive a JSON object from using the below code

```
var tbl = $('#myTable tr:has(td)').map(function(i,v){
    var $td = $('td', this);
    return{
        id:$td.eq(0).text(),
        column1:$td.eq(1).text(),
        column2:$td.eq(2).text()

    }
    }).get();
```

This works perfect except from one thing, I sometime have a textbox or checkbox inside a td whose value I need to retrieve. I've Google'd and searched StackOverflow but I could not find any that worked in this situation

I have also tried the follow with no luck

```
id:$td.eq(0).val()
id:$td.eq(0).childern().val()
```

any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post some sample markup?

Comment: A checkbox does'nt really have a value unless you explicitly give it a value, otherwise it's just on or off, wich you determine with `.prop('checked')`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably want to [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the input if its something like a textbox:

```
$td.eq(0).find('input').val()
```

for a checkbox, use the [pseudo-selector `:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) and determine its `checked` property

```
$td.eq(0).find(':checkbox').prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need value and text then use something like this:

```
id:$td.eq(0).find(':checkbox').attr('value') + $td.eq(0).text();
```

If you need value only then:

```
id:$td.eq(0).find(':checkbox').attr('value');
```

By the way, jQuery team recommended (check comments below) using .find() instead of $(target, context);
In your example:

```
var $td = $('td', this);
```

should look like:

```
var $td = $(this).find('td');
```

Comment: there's no need to use `attr('value')` - `val()` will do. But as commented, checkboxes dont necessarily have a value.

Comment: "*...  jQuery team recommend...*", reference needed?

Comment: Sorry, can't find that article on jquery.com. Saw that 1-2 years ago, mb they reworked this moment already. Anyway - direct method call always works faster. Tested it 2 minutes ago - in big selections, $(element).find(terget) always works 2-5ms faster than $(target, context). You can test it by yourself using console.time().